# How do I correctly convert enemy saving throws so that players roll all the dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules

Much in the same vein as [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60634/what-are-the-implications-of-using-ac-rolls-for-defense) question, I am trying to convert 5e so players roll all the dice. I'm using [this variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/adventuring/playersRollAllTheDice.htm) as a starting framework that seems to work well with 5e so far, without changing monster vs. player statistics.

My stumbling block is spell saves. Take a humble goblin and his +2 dex vs. a high level save of 19 (8+6+5). He has a 4/20 chance of passing that save. If I stick to the same-ish formula of 14+2 vs. (caster mod)+proficiency on the players’ side, I end up with the goblin having 4/20 of saving.

I am looking to convert spell save DCs from 8+proficiency+caster mod vs d20+ stat mod+proficiency fairly. I think 14+saving throw does so correctly, and fairly. If not I want someone to tell me why that’s wrong.